# Contextual difference 2 sentences

Tags: meaning-in-context

Like tomorrow never comes VS like there is no tomorrow. Do the sentences have contextual difference or they are interchangeable?

Comment: They *mean* the same thing; however, *like there is no tomorrow* is an idiom, while *like tomorrow never comes* is not. The second would not sound natural.

Comment: Both are usually used to describe someone's reckless actions and means that the person acted as if they did not care if they survived until tomorrow. For example _"He free climbs {climbing without ropes} like there is no tomorrow"_

Comment: @jason, while "tomorrow never comes" may not be an idiom, it is a common phrase. Google Ngrams shows its usage as being quite close to that of "there is no tomorrow" in some years higher. The similar phrase *If tomorrow comes* was the title of a popular novel and of a mini-series based on it.

Comment: @DavidSiegel *Do it like tomorrow comes* is not common as far I've ever heard. It's an awkward mixing of tenses. To sound natural to me, it should instead be *Do it like tomorrow **will never** come.* The only reason that *do it like there **is** no tomorrow* sounds okay is simply because it's an idiom that everybody uses. If it *weren't* an idiom, it, too, would be awkward, and would normally be replaced with *do it like there **will be** no tomorrow.*